# Date criteria for Google search

Tags: google-search

Sometimes I'm looking for date-sensitive information and don't want to see results more than a certain age.  Is there a way to specify this in a Google search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

- Go to Google's Advanced Search Page
- Expand the `Date, Usage Rights, NumericRange, and More` section

[image: Date Advanced Search]

- Choose from the following options

  - Past 24 hours
  - Past week
  - Past month
  - Past year

OR

- Do a regular Google Search
- Expand the <del>**Show**</del> Search tools <del>on the left</del> underneath the search field
- Choose from the following options.

[image: Search Tools]

Before:
[image: Show Search Tools]

These options appear in the query string. I don't think there is a way to include them in the regular search input as a search operator.  In other words, I don't think it can be used like the filetype search term.

Answer (score 4):

Once you preform the Google search, you can click on **More search tools** and then **Custom Range...**

This will use the publication date, which Google [describes](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142143) as:

> Limit results according to when they
>   were published on the Web. Google
>   tries to estimate the publication date
>   for a page by using information such
>   as the date when Google first indexed
>   the page.

If want to search for pages which contain a date (year only) within a given range, you can use the [Numrange search feature](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35890#numrange). (e.g. `Willie Mays 1950..1960`.)