# Search Engine that will return results based on date

Tags: google-search, date

**Is there a way to use a search engine, preferably Google, that will yield results based on a date?**

For example, *I would like to search on a term and only return results as if I was searching for that term back in the year 2005*.  The results should not have any web page results from 2006 and forward because they did not exist in 2005.

It would be great if it could be specific beyond year, to say a specific month and day: July 1, 2005 for example.

In Google, under Advanced Search, I only see a way to filter by Date by relevance to the current date by: anytime, past 24 hours, past week, past month, and past year.

Comment: Similar to: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5033/date-criteria-for-google-search

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Google:

- Do a search as usual
- Click on the `Search tools` option in the menu bar and then on `Custom range`
- Pick your desired date or type it into the `To:`-field
- Click on `Go`.

[image: Options]

[image: Custom range]