# Is there a way to use Google, to get results from the past?

Tags: google-search

In other words, is there a way to exclude results from after a certain date in Google, or in some other web browser?

Use case: a recent film with a one-word, common-dictionary-word title and a big advertising budget might have semantically tainted an otherwise simple search. Rather than putting a minus on the name of the director, protagonist's actor, and protagonist, it would be simpler (userwise) to exclude results from after the movie was announced. **How can one do that?**

Comment: On google, you can check for results in a given time, like past month, pas year, or even a custom range.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search Engine that will return results based on date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5040/search-engine-that-will-return-results-based-on-date) (Please bear in mind that this link point to a very old question, nowadays the rules to post question on this site are different)

Comment: Related [Date criteria for Google search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/5033/88163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Google Search results page

1. Click Tools
2. Click Anytime
3. Click the appropriate option

[image]

Comment: ...b-b-bu-but... how long was that there?

Comment: This [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/5041/88163) has the same info, it's from 2010