# How do I search the Web for pages posted before a certain date?

Tags: google, search-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date criteria for Google search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5033/date-criteria-for-google-search)
>   [How to do a Google search for webpages last updated within 2 years?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17417/how-to-do-a-google-search-for-webpages-last-updated-within-2-years)

I'm looking for information on a certain topic, but there's been an explosion of forum discussion about it quite recently that's not relevant to what I'm trying to find.  I'd like to eliminate this from my results by searching only for pages posted before a specific date.

[Google Advanced Search](http://www.google.ca/advanced_search) has a date option that allows you to eliminate posts *older* than a certain age by selecting past 24 hours, past week, past month, or past year.  I'd like the opposite of that.  I'd like to eliminate any pages posted in the past six months.  Is there a way to do this in Google, or any other major search engine?

Comment: @Alex That's the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Comment: The answer is the same but the question is different.

Comment: You just set the range to exclude the last six months.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select `Custom range` in the Google's results page's sidebar and set `From` field to a date in the past and `To` field to `1/1/1900`. However, if Google is unable to determine a page's date, it will be eliminated from the results despite being old enough to be matched.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it was only available from the results page.