# Searching for results within a date range from search bar

Tags: google-search

I know we can [specify a date range](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/5034/9381) for the Google search results by clicking in *Search Tools* and changing **Any time** to the dates we want. Is it possible to do the same directly from the search bar using operators?

For instance, in [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) and [Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en) you can use the operators `after` and `before`.

Answer (score -1):

```
daterange:startdate-enddate
```

(In Julian dates.)

You just have to do a separate Google search to determine the Julian date first.

Comment: The _Julian_ dates? So Google uses a calendar system that was abolished in 1582? I would like to know the source for this information, because it sure sounds interesting.

Comment: @Jule: Pretty sure it's the meaning of "Julian date" [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day). We don't call them "Gregorian dates" even though we use the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Here's more information: http://reviews.cnet.com/4520-10165_7-6206764-2.html  For most people, though, Julian dates are going to be non-trivial to figure out, so I don't know that this answer is really viable.

Comment: Ah, suddenly the answer is starting to make at least some sense. Thank you!